# Area of triangle under vector geometry

Tags: vectors

> Calculate the are of a triangle whose vertices are
>   $A(2,1)$, $B(5,-1)$ and $C(3,-2)$

I'm unable to find its dot product,including its formula.

Please, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

the area of a triangle can be computed like $$A=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{a}\times \vec{b}|$$
$$\vec{AC}=[1;-3]$$ and $$\vec{AB}=[3,-2]$$
can you compute the cross product?
the cross product is given by $$0\vec{i}+0\vec{j}+7\vec{k}$$ thus the area is given by $$A=\frac{7}{2}$$

Comment: No,I cannot compute it

Comment: should i compute it for you?

Comment: yes sir,I'll be very grateful if you can.